# Getting sudo to ask for password via the GUI

Tags: macos, osx-lion, sudo

I have a lua script, running on the Mac, that needs to call sudo.

I'd hoped that Mac OS would automatically bring up a password request dialog, but instead it the command fails by returning 256.

Is there anyway that I can achieve my goal?

Tim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any graphical "sudo" for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517183/is-there-any-graphical-sudo-for-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Quick and easy way: run it like this

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "/path/to/myscript args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
```

Proper and configurable way: use `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` API from Authorization Services (in Security.framework).

Both will display standard Mac OS X GUI asking for administrator password and then execute the command as root, the same way as sudo does except that `SUDO_USER` environment variables will not be set.

If you need to execute individual commands from under user account when you're already elevated to root, you can prepend them with `/usr/bin/sudo -u $USER`.

Comment: Hey @hamstergene by the last sentence you mean like this?

`osascript -e 'do shell script "sudo -u $USER /path/to/myscript args 2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'`

Because this does not work on my end. I get this:

`execution error: sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use thsudo: a password is required (1)d input or configure an askpass helper`