# Starting process from Adobe AIR requires credentials?

Tags: macos, apache, actionscript-3, air, sudo

I'm trying to write a script to start apache:

```
var result = app.doShellScript('apachectl start');
```

and standard out says:

> This operation requires root.

So I change it to:

```
var result = app.doShellScript('sudo apachectl start');
```

And then the response is:

> no tty present and no askpass program specified

In a few other AIR apps AIR would open up a window. Is there some way to prompt this directly?

Comment: Maybe **gksudo** instead of **sudo**?

Comment: @Organis The response I get is `sh: gksudo: command not found`

Comment: I don't know what distro you are on, I'm on Ubuntu and **gksudo** here is GUI alternative of **sudo**, it provides a standard system GTK auth window to auth the next command.

Comment: I might not see it because I'm on OSX

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517183/is-there-any-graphical-sudo-for-mac-os-x