# macos + C# : how can I start process with sudo prompt

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I have an application built in C# .dotnet 6 on macos.

I want the application to be able to seamlessly update itself.

It's downloads the latest pkg and my problem is how I run it.

I want to start this process using "sudo installer -pkg /tmp/mypackage.pkg -target /" but sudo ask for password on the standard input.

How can I start a process with escalated privileges where the user permissions are asked first through something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use AppleScript to create a graphical authentication prompt:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
osascript -e "do shell script \"$*\" with administrator privileges"
```

Other methods: [Is there any graphical "sudo" for Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1517183/4088472)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the option `-S` of sudo for accepting the password from standard input. After use echo password and `|` to pass the password to the command:

```
echo myPassword | sudo -S installer -pkg /tmp/mypackage.pkg -target
```